# Laravel Updates existing DB values to NULL

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to Update Form Values that have multiple form Fields. Everything works well only while Updated `DB` `laravel` updates null values in `DB`, which removes existing data in the field.

My controller receives form field requests. When the record is present e.g. three and `fFour` holds old values in `DB`, and I try to only update one and two fields it also updates three and four to null as I only send one and two values.

```
public function updateSystemSettings(Request $request){
    // Validate Request
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'one' => 'string|nullable',
        'two' => 'string|nullable',
        'three' => 'json|nullable',
        'four' => 'json|nullable',
        etc.. other null or holds values
    ]);
    if($validator->fails()){
        return response()->json($validator->errors()->toJson(), 400);
    }

    // Get First Row if Exist ELSE I will create record
    $systemSettings = SystemSettings::first();
    // Update
    $result = array_filter(request()->all());
    SystemSettings::where('id', $systemSettings->id)->update([
        "one" => $result['one'],
        "two" => $result['two'],
        "three" => $result['three'],
        other fields...
    ]);

    // After update Send Updated Dat
    $data = SystemSettings::first();
    $response = json_decode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
    return response()->json([
        'data' => $response
    ]);
}
```

Tried almost everything, in `SQL` we have something called values(?, ?, ?, ?, ? ) which only updates the fields which has values else it keeps the old `DB` values as is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to check if the request has the key (e.g. three):

```
SystemSettings::where('id', $systemSettings->id)->update([
    "one" => $result['one'] ?? $systemSettings->one,
    "two" => $result['two'] ??  $systemSettings->two,
    "three" => $result['three'] ??  $systemSettings->three,
    other fields...
]);
```

FYI:

```
"one" => $result['one'] ?? $systemSettings->one
```

is eqaul to

```
"one" => $result['one'] ? $result['one'] : $systemSettings->one
```